# Get ID from selected row in DataGridView to print in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Simply just I want to reflect the Id number in selected row from DataGridView

I have tried this

```
tb_id.Text = dgv_search.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

tb_id is my textbox and dgv_search is the DataGridView

I got the result of first row even if I select another row

Comment: You aren't showing us where you are calling that code.

Comment: after a button clicked

Comment: Is the button event properly subscribed?  Did you use the debugger to test it when you click the button.  Otherwise, the posted code works.

Comment: Yes it worked fine but it show first row id and that's not what i want (I want to show selected row id ) I have tried to select another rows but the textbox value not changed

Comment: Like I said, the posted code works.  You're doing something we can't see.  Post the code that recreates the problem for us.

Comment: `tb_id.Text = dgv_search.CurrentRow?.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your words say you want the Id in the **selected row** but your *code* says to use the first value in the `SelectedCells` collection. Try making your code match your intent by using the `SelectedRows` collection instead.

```
dgv_search.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(dgv_search.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        var rowIndex = dgv_search.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        var columnIndex = dgv_search.Columns["Id"].Index;
        tb_id.Text = dgv_search[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
};
```